# multiple use of ++: more efficient if I force the evaluation from right to left?

Tags: haskell

I want to append 3 lists or more at once in a single expression.

```
a ++ b ++ c
```

Will the ++ operator will be evaluated from left to right or right to left?

```
1. (a ++ b) ++ c
2. a ++ (b ++ c)
```

I would say option 2, because if ++ was a prefix function, we would write `++ a ++ b c` which naturally leads to evaluating `++ b c` first. I'm not sure if I'm correct.

But if it's option 1, it seems to me that explicitely changing the order of evaluation from right to left is more efficient:

```
a ++ (b ++ c)
```

Here is why: `a ++ b ++ c` will first evaluate to `ab ++ c` in n steps (where n is the length of a and ab is of course the concatenation of a and b) and then to `abc` in n+m more steps (m being the length of b, thus n+m the is the length of ab), which makes a total of 2n+m steps. Whereas `a ++ (b ++ c)` will first evaluate to `a ++ bc` in m steps, and then to `abc` in n more steps, which is a total of n+m steps only.

I'm new to haskell and not sure about what I'm saying, I'd like some confirmation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a ++ b ++ c
```

is parsed as

```
a ++ (b ++ c)
```

for exactly the reasons you describe: had `(++)` been left-associative, then `a ++ b ++ c` would copy `a` twice. You can check this in GHCi with

```
Prelude> :i (++)
```

which will respond with

```
infixr 5 ++
```

where `infixr` means "infix, right-associative".

Answer (score 6):

From `ghci`, do a `:i`:

```
Prelude> :i (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]   -- Defined in GHC.Base
infixr 5 ++
```

Which shows that `++` is (infix and) right-associative, and will be evaluated right-to-left.  I don't know, but I would be willing to bet that whoever implemented that had your question in mind when he/she made it right-associative.

Comment: And that infixr means that without parentheses, it's option 2.

Comment: I suppose I should have emphasized that explicitly!

Comment: Yes, the associativity of ++ was picked exactly to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Also there is `concat` function which concatenates any number of lists:

```
Prelude> :t concat
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
Prelude> concat [[1], [2,3], [42,911]]
[1,2,3,42,911]
```